# Trying to get gparted on ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, gparted

I'm new to Ubuntu and really enjoy it. Usually I can find help just by googling cause stuff is so well documented. But I can't figure this problem out when I try to install gparted I get this error. Any ideas?! Any help is appreciated.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gparted : Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 2.42.0) but 2.39.93-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
           Depends: libparted-fs-resize0 (>= 3.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libparted2 (>= 3.1) but it is not installable
           Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Also try `dpkg --configure -a` to make sure everything has been set up.

Comment: those are the dependencies for the vivid version of gparted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to install the wrong version, possibly from a downloaded source. One of the first bad habits you have break coming from windows is downloading software.

I know how it can be to be used to downloading an .exe from where ever and running it to install but Ubuntu has a secure repository containing tens of thousands of apps preconfigured for your specific arch and version (no more downloaded viruses!).

To install gparted (or any software for that matter) you have a few choices.

---

**First**, you can do this via the command line line by executing the following two commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

If you still get the same errors, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted=0.18.0-1
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gparted=0.18.0-1
```

You should have the proper dependencies available for this version (0.18.0-1).

**Also**, to search for software via the command line you can execute the following commands:

```
apt-cache search gparted
```

To narrow the search results, use grep like so:

```
apt-cache search gparted | grep gparted
```

---

**Next**, use the ubuntu software center:

This method is probably the easiest, just search for software center on your dash, open the app, do a search, and if you see something you want to install, click install.

---

**Finally**, use the synaptic package manager:

To install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synaptic policykit-1
```

Then, to run synaptic, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, type:

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Search for and select software. Click on apply to install selected applications.

You can even use synaptic to fix broken packages. Just open synaptic, select "fix broken packages" from the "Edit" menu, and then click "Apply". Note: always review changes before accepting to ensure you do not uninstall something you need to keep.

Comment: `synaptic` in a terminal with `sudo`? -1

Comment: @A.B. I fixed it :)

Comment: Now I like your answer +1

Comment: @A.B. good shot, I should've figured out a right way to do that a while ago

Comment: I especially like `synaptic-pkexec`

Comment: sudo apt-get install gparted=0.18.0-1 worked like a charm. So I got the ppa from a tutorial on installing gparted. I guess it was the wrong version. Thanks for the fast response I will keep this in mind for future installations.

Comment: @Undead_Atomsk if you need to or want to, you can uninstall the ppa by deleting the file for the ppa in /etc/apt/sources.list.d and then run `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update`.